# Integral with Fresnel functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$I=\int\sqrt{t}\sin(t)\mbox{d}t$

How to calculate $I$ ?

I know, that the answer is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}t\right)-\sqrt{t}\cos(t) +\mbox{const}$, where $C(u)$ is Fresnel cosine : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html.

Comment: Right, it was stupid question :P

Comment: Maybe there's a shortcut or another way to do it. idk